# Reviewing same file multiple times = same question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I think code review is the best thing ever and that I need code review basically daily since I change the code daily. I don't posted too much, only 3 or 4 questions how to clean python and yaml and I'm getting great help. If you want you can inspect my account and warn me if I post things that could be too irrelevant to others or too stupid questions.

I anyway think that code review is the best and I would like to see for example connecting my open source repository to volutary code reviewers that can review my daily or weekly changes and be some "code police" on me. I think it is good with "code police" since I realize I make many mistakes which also can be seen from reading my questions.

So I'm basically asking for a way to subscribe to code review if you know? Is this the best forum?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, Code Review would not be the best place for that kind of review. The best code for this site, as I see it, is code you consider finished. It works, it's the best you can think of, and you're ready to get it critiqued.

What you are describing is better for a small group of developers that constantly review each other's work. A fair comparison would be an agile team working on the same project: they constantly see all the changes and improve each other's code as they go. I would suggest you try to find a couple of other developers to work with, or join a developer group near you. They can give you the constant sort of feedback you are looking for.

Comment: Good point that I shoud not review something I don't really stand for